# Prove a finite Abelian group with no subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p \oplus \Bbb Z_p$ for any prime $p$ is cyclic without using quotients.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove a finite Abelian group with no subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p \oplus \Bbb Z_p$ for any prime $p$ is cyclic without using quotients.

I see that no subgroup has order $p^2$ and $|G| \neq p^2$ for every prime number.  Because of this I can see that $|G| = 1, 2, 3$ are all cyclic, but would there be a way to prove this inductively past $|G| = 3$?

Comment: This follows immediately from the classification of finite abelian groups. Also, your first conclusion is wrong: take $G = \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your first sentence?

Comment: What do you want me to elaborate on? The result completely classiifes finite(ly generated) abelian groups; just look at the ones that don't contain $\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: What do you mean by it follows from the classification of finite abelian groups?  I don't understand what you mean by classification of finite abelian groups.  Does it just mean they're finite and abelian?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification

Comment: The book I'm reading hasn't covered direct sums or normal subgroups yet.  Is there a way to show this without referencing that classification?  Because I don't want to skip chapters.

Comment: @Oliver You say that the book has not covered direct sums, but the problem you are asking has a direct sum in the statement; how is this so?

Comment: The book I'm reading refers to those symbols as external direct products.  Are those the same as direct sums?

Comment: @OliverG Yes they are the same.

Comment: In the future, if you post an exercise from a source, then please cite the source. And in particular, where the exercise appears in the book. The location (for instance the topic of the chapter it appears in and which lemmas appear before it in the book) may help your readers understand the authors intent for what is supposed to be used in the answer.

Comment: After searching, this appears to be exercise 50 in the supplementary exercises for chapters 5-8.

Comment: I'm doing every exercise in the book, and this seems to be a precursor to normal groups and the fundamental theorem of ableian groups.  I don't know how I'd prove this without using those theorems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|G| = n<\infty$, and by the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic, $n$ has a prime factorization of the form $n = \prod_{i\in I} p_i ^{\alpha_i}$. However, there is a fundamental theorem of abelian groups stating that $G$ is therefore isomorphic to a direct sum of the form $ \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{\beta_i}}$. Note here that the exponent did change, since there are multiple possibilities that this group could be isomorphic to (in fact, $\prod p(\alpha_i)$ possiblities, where $p(.)$ denotes the partition function).

With this, there is ALSO another theorem stating that the direct sum of groups of the form $\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{m_i} $ is cyclic if and only if each $m_i$ is coprime with the rest. Then the result follows, since clearly $p$ is not relatively prime to itself.

Comment: The book I'm reading hasn't covered direct sums yet, is there a way to solve this without referring to them?

Comment: @OliverG What do you think $\Bbb Z_p\oplus\Bbb Z_p$ is?

Comment: The book I'm reading refers to those symbols as external direct products.

Comment: May I ask what book you are using?

Comment: @OliverG Usually one calls $A\times B$ a product and $A\oplus B$ a sum (notice the symbols), but in any case they are one and the same thing for abelian groups.

Comment: @arctictern I feel like the book he is reading may be geared toward purely group theory -- if you look up external direct product it is literally the same thing as a direct sum. Perhaps it is more advantageous to use this terminology when using mulitplicative notation because student may get confused that a direct sum is actually a product of $n$-tuples.

Comment: No, I am telling you why the book he is reading might have altered the terminology.

Comment: The book I'm reading is "Contemporary abstract algebra: by Joseph Gallian."

Comment: By "this terminology" do you mean the $\oplus$ symbol alongside the phrase "direct product" in the absence of the phrase "direct sum"? Personally, I think having ($\oplus$ and "direct sum" for additive groups) and ($\times$ and "direct product" for multiplicative groups) would be ideal.

Comment: @arctictern I agree

Comment: @OliverG Does the answer make sense now that you know direct sums and external direct products are the same?

Comment: I haven't learned the fundamental theorem of abelian groups yet, but does it imply that each ${p_{i}^{k_i}}$ and ${p_{j}^{k_j}}$ in $\oplus \Bbb Z _{p_{a}^{k_a}}$ are coprime and therefore is an abelian group?

Comment: Well, the direct sum (or product) of abelian groups is still abelian -- did you mean cyclic?

Comment: Yes, cyclic is what I meant.

Comment: Then yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Use primary component, we have the claim that the form will be $Z_{p_1}^{r_1}⊕Z_{p_2}^{r_2}⊕…⊕Z_{p_s}^{r_s}$, since $p_i$and$p_j$ are coprime, then it is cyclic.

To prove the claim, we assume $Z_{p_1}^{r_{1,1}}⊕Z_{p_1}^{r_{1,2}}$, then both groups have a p-order subgroup and they are disjoint, so we have induced group isomorphic to $Z_{p}⊕Z_{p}$, it is a contradiction.